# Excel Count Number of Items if Same Year Across Multiple Worksheet Specific Cell

Tags: excel-formula, sumproduct

I have about 50 worksheets, each Worksheet contains specific cell (G11) in date format (dd-mmm-yy); other 5 worksheets used for other purpose.

What I need to do, first, to check cell G11 in the 50 worksheets match to current year and current month, then, count total number of G11 that meets current year and current month across all 50 worksheets. Finally, the counted number will be reflected in separate worksheet.

I had tried SUMPRODUCT or 3-D Reference, but I got return with #VALUE!. A2 is current mmm-yy; Sheet Name in 4 digit numbering:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(INDIRECT("'"&Table[Sheet Name]&"'!$G$11"),"mmm-yy")=TEXT(A2,"mmm-yy")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
=SUM(--(TEXT(N(INDIRECT("'"&Table[Sheet Name]&"'!$G$11")),"mmm-yy")=TEXT(A2,"mmm-yy")))
```

or

```
=SUM(--(TEXT(N(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(11,7,,,Table[Sheet Name]))),"mmm-yy")=TEXT(A2,"mmm-yy")))
```

If you have lower than Excel 2016, you have to do CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter this formula.

Comment: Awesome!! May I ask, what is the rationale behind? If it is easy to share. Why can't I just pick up G11 date value and convert via TEXT() to "mmm-yy"?

Comment: N is one of the strangest functions. I use it most frequently to comment simple formulas (e.g., `=32+N("level 1 tickets/mo")+9+N("level 2 tickets/mo")`) or to protect formulas from errors when inputting text where a number is expected (e.g., `=N(B1)+A2` where B1 has a column header). In its normal application, there is no magic, but there is a magic when applying it to an array of INDIRECT calls, such as your case. To me, your formula should work. When you EVALUATE it, you can see that it blows up when the INDIRECT array is created. N forces the VALUE errors back to original values. Crazy.